# MySQL: select items not in a list

Tags: mysql

How can I select items that are in a list but not in the table? For example, if I am given a list like: `'apple', 'banana', 'carrot'` and I have a table like:

```
fruit:
------
apple
banana
```

I want the result of my query to come as `'carrot'`, since it was the element in the list provided that is not present in the table. How do I do this?

Comment: You're probably going to have to fetch the values which ARE in the table and then remove them from the list if you're using MySQL. Something which could be more scalable is a series pipelined `EXISTS` to keys (or perhaps `SISMEMBER` to a set) in a Redis database if you're not opposed to using other technologies.

Comment: @Michael Mior: there is absolutely no reason to move to Redis just because of one query

Comment: @zerkms Agreed. Unless that query is critical to your application and you can't find a way to make it run fast. I'm suggesting it as a last resort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to put your list in a table as well:

```
Table fruitable:
fruit 
------
apple
banana

Table fruitable_list:
fruit
------
apple
banana
carrot
```

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT fruitable_list.fruit FROM fruitable_list
LEFT JOIN fruitable
  ON fruitable.fruit = fruitable_list.fruit
WHERE fruitable.fruit IS NULL
```

Results in:

```
fruit
------
carrot
```

It's hard to return a record in a result set that's not in the data set.

Comment: Yeah, and probably make the table `TEMPORARY`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT v.fruit FROM (
    SELECT 'apple' AS fruit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'banana'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'carrot') v
LEFT JOIN friuttable ft ON ft.fruit = v.fruit
    WHERE ft.fruit IS NULL
```

<strike>Another:</strike>

```
SELECT fruit
  FROM fruittable
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(fruit, 'apple,banana,carrot') = 0
```

Comment: @luqita: Yeah, didn't pretend to be universal solution but cannot think of anything else. Curious about solution that will fit thousands of items.

Comment: @luqita: probably got another one

Comment: just gives me all the fruits that are in the table but not in the list (has to be the other way around, all fruits that are not in the table but are in the list)