# How to find every entry in a given list values that does not exist in a mysql table?

Tags: mysql

First I have a mysql table containing product data, including an EAN code (nothing special, just a numeric code).

Second I have list of EAN code values. This list is not stored in any table, it´s created by user input.

Is there a way to find every EAN code from my list that does NOT exist in the product table, without storing the EAN list in a table first?

For example, assume the following data in the products table:

```
id: 1, ean: 12345
id: 2, ean: 23456
```

And the list to compare:

```
12345,23456,88888,99999
```

In this case the desired result would be

```
88888,99999.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: select items not in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902654/mysql-select-items-not-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT tmp_list.ean FROM (
                          SELECT 12345 AS ean UNION
                          SELECT 23456 AS ean UNION
                          SELECT 88888 AS ean UNION
                          SELECT 99999 AS ean
                         ) AS tmp_list
                    WHERE ean NOT IN (
                                       SELECT ean FROM table_name
                                     )
```

It can be helpful if you are having less number of list elements.

Comment: Currently I do not have an answer in terms of sql query, but you can make the query using for loop in any language. I'll try to give the sql query soon. Thanks