# Query for missing items in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of airport code pairs:

```
|iata|icao|
-----------
|ORD |KORD|
|JFK |KJFK|
|LAX |KLAX|
|SFO |KSFO|
```

I want to run a query that will return the codes that do not exist in this table, so if I run a query (against the iata column) containing ATL,ORD,MIA,SFO it would return ATL and MIA since neither of those exist in my table.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can have a table that has all the possible airport codes and then join with the table above to check what is missing. Or you need to individually check for each airport code against the table.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902654/mysql-select-items-not-in-a-list) of how this could work in MySQL; the concepts should transfer to `sqlite3`, as well.

Comment: Excellent, I can work with that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a query that runs code, here is one way:

```
    select mc.*
    from (<your query goes here>) mc
    where mc.iata not in (select iata from AirportCodePairs acp)
```

You can also do this with a `left outer join` and comparison to `NULL`.  I would recommend an index on `iata` in the pairs table.

Or, if you don't have a query, you can do:

```
    select mc.*
    from (select 'ATL' as code union all
          select 'ORD' union all
          select 'MIA' union all
          select 'SFO'
         ) mc
    where mc.iata not in (select iata from AirportCodePairs acp)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this, where did "mc" come from and what do you mean by a query that runs code?

Comment: @Ralgha . . . Your question says that you have a query that returns the codes you are interested in.  That query goes where the `<your query goes here>` is.  The `mc` is a table alias and is a basic part of the SQL language.

Comment: Ah this works and doesn't need a temporary table, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with the values you are searching for and then do a JOIN:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp ( code char(3) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO tmp (code) VALUES ('ATL'), ('ORD'), ('MIA'), ('SFO');

SELECT code FROM tmp
LEFT OUTER JOIN  airportcode as ac ON tmp.code = ac.iata
WHERE ac.iata IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

in oracle you could use minus command example

```
select your_columns from tableA minus select your_columns from tableB
```

note that both must have same columns and types and lengths or it will not work.

if type is different do cast, to_char, to_date or whatever function is necessary to get types the same.  Note if you do have to do one of these or any oracle function call in where clause then use function based indexes.  For example, if to_upper is called in where clause like this

```
select * from tableName a where to_upper(last_name)='SIMPSON'
```

an index on this would be created as follows

```
create index ixt on tableName(to_uppper(last_name));
```